# Is there a way for PHP PDO to detect if a t-sql database is being restored?

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, database-connection

I'd like my PHP script (using PDO) to detect whether or not a target database is in the middle of a restore process other than waiting several minutes for a response from a failed connection.

My database connection code eventually returns the message below if a database is being restored, but it happens because the connection fails and it takes several minutes to respond when this happens. Searching on StackOverflow and Google doesn't seem to find anything that fits my need, nor does searching through PHP's documentation.

```
function getParameterizedPDOConnection($host = false, $overrideOptions = []) {
    include(INCLUDE_DIR . "/itrain.config.php");
    $host = strtolower($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]);

    if (count($overrideOptions) > 0) {
        $configOptions["host"][$host] = $overrideOptions;
    }

    $sthUserName = $configOptions["userName"];
    $pwd = $configOptions["pwd"];
    $addr = $configOptions["host"][$host]["addr"];
    $db = $configOptions["host"][$host]["db"];

    try {
        $pdo = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=$addr;Database=$db;ConnectionPooling=0", $sthUserName, $pwd, array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT));
        return($pdo);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        return "Database connection failure: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Returns: "42000",927,"[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Database 'Workforce' cannot be opened. It is in the middle of a restore.

Comment: [this](https://www.nucleustechnologies.com/blog/fixed-database-cannot-be-opened-as-it-is-in-the-middle-of-a-restore/) may help.

Comment: I don't know what that link is supposed to help... My first thought is to do this before you run your other queries: `SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX ('YourDB', 'Status'))` and if the Status = RESTORING then wait for some amount of time and retry. It's quick and dirty so maybe someone has a better approach.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/databasepropertyex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15